# Using Replace in SELECT * statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

How can I work this REPLACE statement I'm using in the following, into my SELECT statement below ? The update works perfectly, but need the same code in the SELECT.

```
$sql1 = ("UPDATE $table SET notes=replace(REPLACE(notes,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),' ') WHERE year='$year'");


$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE SUBSTR(week_start_date,-4)=$startDate AND week_num = '$week' AND archived!='yes' ORDER BY fn,ln";
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If you do the `REPLACE` first you don't have to change your `SELECT`. Or are you wanting to test first, before the `INSERT`?

Comment: What happens when you try it?   Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in your table that has CRLF that you want to `REPLACE` with `' '`, you can't use the `SELECT *` notation - you have to tell it *which* column you want to replace the characters in.  You'll have to do something like this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(notes, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') as fixed_notes FROM $table ...`
```

In general, it's best to avoid using `SELECT *`, and always to specify the columns you want (as well as any scalar functions you want to run on said columns) explicitly.  This way, if the table definition adds more columns, you don't start getting data you never intended to process; and if a column gets dropped, you'll know **that** was the cause rather than something else in your presentation layer.  It also means that it'll be possible to manipulate the individual columns in the statement where appropriate.

If you can live with these limitations, and you don't mind having the column appear twice, you could do this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, REPLACE(REPLACE(notes, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') as fixed_notes FROM $table ...`
```

Comment: I'm assuming they don't want the column twice in their list, but I guess that would work.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well they could alias the column with the Replacements to whatever they wanted.   In fact, if they don't alias it, they'll get a column with no name.   (or at least, that's what SQL Server would return.)